# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Trying to compile an example project for Android, but gradle complains it can't find **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+** dependency. It makes sense because my local repos only have **26.0.0-alpha1** and older. Tried adding `maven.google.com` or `google()` to `build.gradle` but that didn't do anything. However viewing Google's maven repo through the browser, I can clearly see it has what I need there! Maybe I need to disable local repos or something, but how?

`gradle build` output, version is 4.4.1:

```
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         26.0.0-alpha1
         25.3.1
         25.3.0
         25.2.0
         25.1.1
         + 31 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/MyApplication/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/MyApplication/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to add "google()" to **allprojects**, and not **buildscript** dependencies. :^) Well this is embarrassing..

just for future reference (3 months later and this crap again). You want your top-level build.gradle look something like (add it also to buildscript for reasons mentioned by [@Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365927/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappcompat-v727#comment83720551_48366078)):

```
...
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            // apparently google() can be used too, but I couldn't get it to work
            // google()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Actually both if you want to build outside of Android Studio.